# Form as Many Possible Mixed-Effect Model Using lme4 Package of R

Tags: r, lme4

I want to form as many models as possible using `lme4` package in `R` with `lmer()` function.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lme4);

gate  = read_csv('gate_data.csv')

m1=lmer(CHG ~  YEAR*BLAREA + YEAR:LOC + YEAR:FOC + YEAR:PSD + YEAR:LAT + YEAR:FAFPAT + (0+YEAR|EYEID), data = gate)
m2 = lmer(CHG ~ YEAR*BLAREA + YEAR:LOC + YEAR:FOC + YEAR:PSD + YEAR:LAT + YEAR:FAFPAT + (1|EYEID), data = gate)
BIC(m1, m2)
```

Using the models `m1` and `m2`, I want more possible models from the variables used in `m1` and `m2` using the `lmer()` function in `lme4` package of `R`.

```
#library(tidyverse)
#library(lme4)

#gate <- read_csv('gate_data.CSV')

# Create a vector of independent variables excluding the dependent variable
independent_vars <- setdiff(names(gate), "CHG")

# Create an empty list to store the models
models <- list()

# Loop through all possible combinations of independent variables
for (i in 1:length(independent_vars)) {
  model_formula <- paste("CHG ~", paste(c(independent_vars[i], "YEAR"), collapse = "*"))

  # Add fixed-effects model to the list
  models[[i]] <- lmer(as.formula(model_formula), data = gate)

  # Add random-intercept model with random intercept for EYEID to the list
  models[[i + length(independent_vars)]] <- lmer(as.formula(model_formula) + (1 | EYEID), data = gate)

  # Add mixed-effects model with random intercept for EYEID and random slope for YEAR to the list
  models[[i + 2 * length(independent_vars)]] <- lmer(as.formula(model_formula) + (1 + YEAR | EYEID), data = gate)
}

# Print the models
models
```

I tried the above but got an `error message:

> No random effects terms specified in formula

Please help me out.

Comment: @BenBolker: I posted it together with a simple example. However, I'm not happy with my construct `formula(sprintf('mpg ~ gear + %s', predictor))` to compose the formula. I'd be grateful for a hint towards improvement!

Answer (score 2):

Your initial model_formula is lacking a random-effect term, thus the first lmer call in your loop throws a corresponding error message.

Note that there's dedicated methods (`update`, `reformulate`, `add1`, `drop1`, `step`) to variate model terms; step [helps to automatize this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214682/stepwise-regression-in-r-how-does-it-work); for automated `lmer` comparisons, {[lmerTest](https://github.com/runehaubo/lmerTestR)} might come in handy.

To illustrate, an example where car mileage (dataset `mtcars`) is modelled from gear count plus a second varying predictor:

```
base_model <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars)

model_collection <- 
  names(mtcars)[-1] |> ## (1)
  Map(f = \(predictor){ ## (2)
    base_model |>
      update(reformulate(c("gear", predictor), response = "mpg")) |> ## (3a)
##    update.formula(new = formula(sprintf('mpg ~ gear + %s', predictor))) |> ## (3b)
      lm(data = get(base_model$call$data)) ## (4)
  })
```

1. omit the first name (`mpg`) which is the dependent variable
2. `Map` the remaining names (instead of looping) ...
3. ... inserting each as an additional predictor (besides `gear`) in the new formula (*credits to [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker) for much improved variant 3a*)
4. `get` those data used for the base model

our collection has one model per additional predictor:

```
## > names(model_collection)
##  [1] "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

inspect a model of our collection:

```
## > model_collection$wt |> summary()

Call:
lm(formula = update.formula(base_model, new = formula(sprintf("mpg ~ gear + %s", 
    predictor))), data = get(base_model$call$data))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-4.1304 -2.3061 -0.2932  1.4409  6.8296 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  38.9157     5.0974   7.634 2.04e-08 ***
gear         -0.3196     0.9265  -0.345    0.733    
wt           -5.4850     0.6987  -7.851 1.17e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 3.092 on 29 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7538,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7369 
F-statistic: 44.41 on 2 and 29 DF,  p-value: 1.488e-09
```

Comment: I would recommend `update(reformulate(c("gear", predictor), response = "mpg"))` instead of `update.formula(...)`